# SQL Server 2016 CU2: Severity level 20 errors for DML on restore of AX Dynamics 7 database with Change Tracking

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, microsoft-dynamics

## Problem:

After we restore a database to a new environment, we are unable to perform DML operations (e.g. update the record) in some specific tables which have change tracking enabled.

## Details:

We have SQL Server 2016 CU2 installed. We have a backup from SQL Server Azure and restored it on SQL Server 2016 CU2. It is a database from AX Dynamics 7 ERP.

Once we restore it, we are getting `severity level 20 errors` in SQL Server log when executing DML statements for some specific tables which have change tracking enabled.

If we disable the change tracking, we are able to execute DML statements without any issue. If we drop the table and recreate them with the script from previous object, the issue permanently vanishes. It then starts working with change tracking enabled as well.

## Question:

How can we resolve this without disabling change tracking and without dropping and recreating the problematic tables?

Comment: I have separated problem and details. can you guys now remove on hold status from my question

Comment: Did you synchronize from visual studio after restoring?

Comment: Can you share the exact error message you are getting when executing the DML statements?